# induction for massive objects

Tags: newtonian-gravity, induction

We know that when two charged bodies are kept near one another, they attract the charges and induce some charge near the surface. This happens even when only lne body is charged as the charges are pulled to one side.

My question is that why doesnt a similar phenomenon takes for mass. As we know that massive particles are attracted by massive particles, then why doesnt the mass of a body get concentrated at one side when placed in gravitational field of another body ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the charge case, we assume that the charges have some freedom of motion (if they are very free, this corresponds to conductors, which are easily polarized; if they are not so free, this corresponds to dielectrics - insulators that can be polarized). For a corresponding effect in the case of mass, you would need mobile mass. For example, a fluid. The earth is (mostly) covered with a large amount of water - and yes, the water (and its mass) does redistribute itself due to gravity. We describe this in terms of [tidal forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force).

Comment: Totally agreed about the fact of mobile particlss of electrostatic induction, but during tides the entire body of water shift, not just redistributes around a fixed body.  I am more interested in knowing whether like electrostatic bodies where some or most of the charge shifts can a body just have a shift like as in shift of centrs of mass due to gravitational induction, may it be negligible.